# Modules to set up audio podcast functionality

Tags: files

I am looking for modules to set up audio podcast functionality which allows playing of uploaded audio files as well as take audio source as external links like iTunes links. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully Tested with combination of

[remote_file_source](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_file_source)

> Remote File Source allows you to add a file from a remote server to a
>   filefield without transferring it locally.

[Jplayer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jplayer)

> The jPlayer module provides a wrapper around the jPlayer JavaScript
>   library. This library provides an HTML5-based player, that uses a
>   Flash fallback for browsers that do not yet support it. This module
>   provides a default presentation for the player, as well as integration
>   with CCK file fields and a display style for Views. This makes it
>   possible to easily convert the display of any file field into an audio
>   player.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FileField Podcaster](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffpc)

> Using Views2, this module delivers a way to podcast with nodes that
>   have CCK FileFields included as RSS file enclosures. It provides a
>   podcast-compatible (as determined by Apple) RSS feed, using node
>   variables, getID3, filefield in cck, and filefield meta data to
>   generate the RSS tags

Comment: thanks @Gokul, this module is on my list, I have a doubt if i handle external links out of the box. Will give a try.